# gnome-terminal will open a new window, when clicked from favorite on dash

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

**Unexpected behaviour:**
When clicking the favorited gnome-terminal icon on dash, it will open a new instance of terminal window and then a new terminal icon will appear beside the favorited icon. If I do another click, it will open a 2nd window. It will be on the same icon as the 1st window.

It will only occur only for gnome-terminal. Other application work as expected.[image: Before], [image: After].

**Step to reproduce:**

1. Add gnome-terminal as favorite on dock
2. Click on the icon

**Expected result:**

Open a terminal window without duplicating the icon, and clicking on the icon should open the existing window instead of new window.

**Attempt:**

- I could not figure out what cause such behaviour but I did change "Open new terminals in" in gnome-terminal Preference from "Window" to "Tab". Although I know it wouldn't have any effect.
- I did turn of Dash to Dock extension and it doesn't fix the problem
- I just upgraded from Pop_OS! 18.04 to Pop_OS! 20.04. Everything work as expected in the previous version.

**Specification:**
Distributor ID: Pop
Description:    Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

Kernel: 5.8.0-7642-generic

GNOME Shell 3.36.4

Any insight or direction would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.